# covariance and variance flip in scala

Tags: scala, type-systems

In ***Scala for the Impatient*** It is said that

***functions are contra-variant in their arguments and covariant in their result type***

This is straightforward and easy to understand ,however in the same topic it says

***However inside a function parameter ,the variance flips- its parameters are covariant***

and it takes the example of [foldLeft](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.5.1/scala/Iterable.html#foldLeft%28B%29) method of [Iterator](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.5.1/scala/Iterable.html)
as :

```
 def foldLeft[B](z : B)(op : (B, A) => B) : B
```

I am not getting it clearly what it says.

I tried some of blogs as

1. http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html
2. http://blog.kamkor.me/Covariance-And-Contravariance-In-Scala/
3. http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/covariance-and-contravariance-in-scala/

But didn't get clear understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function is always contravariant in its argument type and covariant in its return type
e.g.

```
trait Function1[-T1, +R] extends AnyRef 

trait Function2[-T1, -T2, +R] extends AnyRef
```

Here, **`T1`,`T2`, ..., `T`n (where n <= `22`) are arguments and `R` is the return type**.

In higher order functions (functions that take function as argument), an argument can have the type parameter that is passed into the function 
e.g. 
`foldLeft` in trait `Iterable`

`Iterable` is declared as

```scala
trait Iterable[+A] extends AnyRef
```

and `foldLeft` is decalred as

```scala
def foldLeft[B](z : B)(op : (B, A) => B) : B
```

Since `A` is declared covariant, it can be used as the return type. But here it is instead an argument type due to

```scala
trait Function2[-T1, -T2, +R] extends AnyRef
```

because `op : (B, A) => B` is the literal type of `Function2`.

The key to this is ***trait `Function2` is contravariant in its argument type***.

Hence covariance type is appearing in method argument due to

> trait Function2 is contravariant in its argument type

This is called ***variance flip***:

1. Flip of covariance is contravariance.
2. Flip of contravariance is covariance.
3. Flip is invariant is invariant.

That's why invariant may appear at any position (covariance/contravariance)

Answer (score 3):

It comes down to what it means for one function to be a subtype of another. It sounds like you are comfortable with A->B is a subtype of C->D if C is subtype of A (contravariant in the input type) and B is a subtype of D (covariant in the return type).

Now consider functions that take other functions as arguments. For example, consider (A->B)->B. We just apply the same reasoning twice. The argument is a function of type A->B and the return type is B. What needs to be true to supply a function of type C->B as the input type? Since functions are contravariant in the input type C->B must be a subtype of A->B. But as we discussed in the first paragraph, that means that A must be a subtype of C. So after two applications of the reasoning in the first paragraph we find that (A->B)->B is covariant in the A position.

You can reason similarly with more complicated functions. In fact, you should convince yourself that a position is covariant if it is to the left of an even number of arrows applying to it.

Comment: In my opinion, this answer actually explains the “why” behind variance flip.

Comment: In my opinion this answer explains the reason like doing a stringent math deduction.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with look at a function as a class or rather a `typeclass` . Think about its type `Function1[-A,+B]`
Say we have the following ,

`class x

 class y extends b`

Now i have two functions like the following ,

```
val test1:x=>Int = //do something
val test2:y=>int = //do something
```

Now if i have another method like the following ,

`def acceptFunction(f: y => Unit, b: B) = //do something`

As per the type signature `Function1[-A,+B]`  i can pass `test2` into `acceptFunction` as well as `test1` because of the `contravariance`. 
Kind of like `test1<:test2` .

This is a completely different thing than saying parameters to a function are covariant.  This means if you have the following ,

```
class  Fruit { def name: String="abstract" }
class Orange extends Fruit { override def name = "Orange" }
class Apple extends Fruit { override def name = "Apple" }
```

You can write the following ,

```
 testM(new Apple())
 def testM(fruit:Fruit)={}
```

But you cannot write this ,

```
     testM(new Fruit())
     def testM(fruit:Apple)={}
```